# How to give a software or app a specific icon?

Tags: icons, icon-themes

I'm currently using the Elementary Icon Pack however the Systems Settings Icon is god-awful and hoping that there is some way to change to an Icon from another Icon pack.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `.desktop` file(usually inside `/usr/share/applications/` for the application you want, then open it with your favorite text editor.

You will see a line starts with `Icon=`. Change the path to the location of the icon(image) you want ;) Good luck!

Comment: That should change the icon in the programs menu, but does it change the icon that's used for the program's own window when it's running?

Comment: I don't think so - since applications can have their own icons.